# Dividir una lista en elementos con posiciones par e impar en Prolog

Tags: prolog

estoy teniendo problemas para desarrollar lo siguiente:
split(L,L1,L2). Dada una lista L de longitud par, L1 debera contener los elementos situados en posiciones pares (N/2) y L2 los impares.

Ejemplo: split([a,b,c,d],X,Y) devolvería X = [a,c], Y = [b,d].

Answer (score 0):

En el caso base, cuando la lista no tiene ningún elemento, tanto la lista de elementos pares como la de impares están vacías:

```
split([], [], []).
```

En el caso recursivo, cuando la lista `[X,Y|T]` tiene al menos dos elementos (`X` e `Y`), el primer elemento (`X`) será la cabeza de la lista de los elementos pares, el segundo elemento (`Y`) será la cabeza de los elementos impares, si `Xs` e `Ys` son las sublistas de la cola `T`.

```
split([X,Y|T], [X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :- split(T, Xs, Ys).
```

[Ejecutar en Tau Prolog](http://tau-prolog.org/sandbox/6mch8xMg)